# HTML & PHP uploader doesn't work

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am playing with an uploader on PHP. Basically,
I did a simple one just for echoing what is chosen from submit button for right now.

```
<? php
echo $name  = $_FILES['file]['name'];

?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctpe="multipart/form-data">

<input type ="file" name="file"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value ="Submit">

</form>
```

I am using [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) and where I located this file is in a folder in htdocs.
apache is running, PHP is running without hesitating whenever I refresh

> http://localhost:81/phpex/upload.php

It just doesn't work and not echoing choosen file name.

Can you tell me what, actually, is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `phpex/upload.php`? And is this page in the `phpex` directory?

Comment: just above what you see in code brackets @BenPearlKahan

Comment: Firstly, you have syntax error `$_FILES['file]['name'];`.
Secondly: remove `action="upload.php"`

Comment: @Kristiyan ok fixed it still not working...secondly without defining action how it is supposed to pass submission into php paragraph?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Kristiyan as you see, input file where name variable is "file" supposed to throw into $_FILES['file']['name']; so that it will return the name for doing this action we gonna need action="upload.php"

Comment: I've just answered you. I told you to remove `action` only for preventing. You can return it. ;)

Comment: If you have fixed the typing mistakes on your side, please take some effort to update the question too. It will help people to focus on the problem rather than your typing mistakes.

Comment: @Kristiyan though it doesnt make sense for me, I have tried what you just said ...nope, it doesnt work

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi, I added it, then i checked console if it threw any error message or not... nope nothing.. as clear as a blank page, so it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Misspelling in your HTML: `enctpe` must be `enctype`.

Also I told you for syntax error `echo $name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];`

Edit:
Already tested:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){ // prevent notice.
echo $name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type ="file" name="file"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value ="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @gobo, I've just edited my answer. You've wrong opening `<?php` tag.
Please just copy/paste my code.

Comment: yours throws error
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpex\upload.php on line 2

Comment: Your code return it. Upload file and it will work. I've change it.

Comment: That is because there is no test to see if `$_FILES` is set before assigning the variable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  
after I fixed syntax
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo $name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type ="file" name="file"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value ="Submit">

</form> 

it gives an error as( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpex\upload.php on line 3

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: I've just edited my answer with if clause to prevent this notice. ;) 
It's not necessary to stop errors. You won't  have problems now. I hope that it was helpful for you ;) Write (read) your code carefully before asking.

Comment: @Kristiyan hi man, ok another thing after echoing, I refresh the page old variables are still staying on the page till i put new value and submit it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $name  = $_FILES['file]['name'];
```

should be

```
echo $name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

- you missed out a quotation mark.

Comment: What is the difference between the two lines?

Comment: `['file']` vs `['file]`

Answer (score 0):

have to show array _files to see all properites :
var_dump($_FILES) ;

your code is correct i think just change name of file

```
 <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" />


 <?php $photo=$_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    echo $photo ;
 ?>
```